# How to display 2 numbers after decimal in Web Page grid view in ASPX Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

This is the table I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
 Product_No AS RIGHT ('PDT0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)),10) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 Product_Image VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
 Product_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Product_Category_No INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product_Category(Product_Category_No),
 Product_Price MONEY NOT NULL,
 Product_Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Grocery_Branch_No INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Grocery_Branch(Grocery_Branch_No)
 )
```

When I insert a value like 10.50 or 100.45 or 11.05 in Product_Price column and then run SELECT * FROM Product in both SQL Server and Visual Studio, the Product_Price column value gets displayed as 10.50 or 100.45 or 11.05.

However, when I see the result of SELECT * FROM Product in a gridview from aspx page, then it shows 10.5000 or 100.4500 or 11.0500.

In other words, the results for Product_Price column value in SQL Server and Visual Studio is showing 2 numbers after the decimal (because in INSERT Statement I have added 2 numbers after decimal).
But, while running the aspx page, in the Product_Price column value in Grid View, it is showing 4 numbers after the decimal.

I made sure to add the Regular Expression Validator for Product_Price column in AddProducts.aspx

```
p>
            Price:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="After decimal only 2 numbers" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</p>
```

Then this is what I have done in my AddProducts.cs

```
Stream stream = postedfile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                byte[] bytes = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                string branch = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddProducts", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", FileUpload1.FileBytes);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategoryName", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", branch);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox("New Product has been added");
```

Then this is what I have done in ViewProducts.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="150px"
          ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png/jpg/jpeg/gif/bmp;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Product_Image")) %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>         
         </asp:TemplateField>        
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Name" HeaderText="Product" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Category_Name" HeaderText="Category" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0} AUD" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Name" HeaderText="Branch" />
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And this is what I have done in ViewProducts.cs

```
 private void DisplayProducts()
        {
            string CS;
            CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewProducts", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
```

I still could not figure out why the ViewProducts.aspx page is showing 4 numbers after the decimal for Product_Price column value in Grid View.

It would be helpful if the recommended syntax solution is provided to display 2 numbers after the decimal for Product_Price column value in Grid View.

Comment: Try `<asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:D2} AUD" />`

Comment: I added that as you have recommended but while  I was trying to run the aspx page it is showing the following error: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code.  But if I remove D2 and try to run the aspx page then it shows the gridview display but the column value is showing 4 numbers after decimal

Comment: What happens if you remove `AUD` and keep `{0:D2}`

Comment: If I remove AUD and keep {0:D2} ..it still shows the same error: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: But if I remove D2 and keep {0} and AUD then the aspx page runs successfully and displays the grid view. But as I said, in the grid view it is showing 4 numbers after decimal for the Product_Price column value.

Comment: Ok try this format `{0:0.00} AUD`

Comment: Now it works ... The gridview successfully displays 2 numbers after column value

Comment: Great, I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Price" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:0.00} AUD" />
```